# How to store local client data in Jsf/richfaces

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

Is it possible to store some amount of local data of client in browser using JSF/Richfaces? I tried to google it but did'nt found any link.I am using richfaces 4 on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot store data on the client side with JSF/Richfaces, because that is a server side technology. But if you want to use the HTML5 Local Storage feature, you should have a look at these links:

- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp
- http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html
- ...

... and many more search results can be found on Google.

On Stackoverflow:

- [Local Storage vs Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies)
- [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage/2010948#2010948)
- ...

Comment: JSF is a server side technology. Simply with JSF you cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in cookies, in session, in database. Any of them work in JSF.